# Are the words "swag" and "sway" cognates?

Tags: etymology

I'm fascinated by the similarities between them, which both refer to some kind of action meaning alike, namely "wavering" action, and they are morphologically alike too.

If they are cognates, in my opinion, these similarities may be explained reasonably.

Comment: Have you checked [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com)?

Comment: @MattЭллен  I'm less and less impressed with Etymonline. It cribs most of its content from *OED*, and usually leaves out most of the evidence and interesting bits. *cf*. tchrist's response below.

Comment: @StoneyB Excellent point, although for folks without OED access it's a good start as a free, valuable resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direct answer to your question is “maybe”.  They aren’t quite sure, which is interesting considering these are words that are relatively new to English.  If you look them up in the OED, they present some theories couched in terms of may and might, and present conflicting evidence.

The OED says of the verb ***sway*** that it is properly two different words from the standpoint of its etymology:

> 1. ME. *sweȝe* (14th c.), conjugated strong and weak, also *swye*, to go, move (cf. ME. *forsueie* to go astray), may have been a native word orig. of the OE. type **sweʒan*, (3 pres. ind. **swiʒeþ*), pa. t. **swæʒ*, parallel to OE. *weʒan* to move, carry, weigh, (*wiʒeþ*), *wæʒ*, ME. *weȝe*, occas. *wye*, pa. t. *weȝe, wei(ȝ), wei(e)de*. (Cf. also the parallelism of *swag* and *wag*, *sweight* and *weight*.) 
>    Formally, *sweʒe* might also be ad. ONor. *sveigja* to bend (a bow), swing (a distaff), etc., give way, yield (cf. *sveigr* switch, twig), causative vb. f. *svig*-, in *svig* bend, curve, *svigi* switch, *svigna* to give way; but the ME. and ONor. verbs do not agree in sense.
> 2. The modern *sway* dates only from c 1500, and agrees in form and sense with, and appears to be ad., LG. *swâjen* to be moved hither and thither by the wind (whence Sw. *svaja* to swing, Da. *svaie* to move to and fro, G. *schwaien*, *schweien*), Dutch *zwaaien* to swing, wave, walk totteringly, slant, bevel.

The verb ***swag*** is now chiefly dialectic. The OED says of its etymology:

> The existence of this verb is perh. attested for the 15th cent. in *swaggyng* (s.v. *swagging* vbl. sb. note), and in *swage* v.2 Its immediate source is uncertain, but it is prob. Scandinavian: cf. Norw. dial. *svagga* and *svaga* to sway (see *sway* v. etym.). 
> The English word might correspond to a Scandinavian form of either type (with -*gg*- or -*g*-), according to dialect; cf., on the one hand, *nag* v. (Norw., Sw. *nagga*), *sag* v. (Norw. dial. *sagga*), *wag* v. (MSw. *wagga*); on the other, *drag* v. (ONor. *draga*), *flag* sb.2 (Icel. *flag*, ONor. *flaga*), *snag* (Norw. dial. *snag*, *snage*); also Sc. *swaw* = undulating or swinging motion, and *flaw* sb.1 (ONor. *flaga*).

The verb ***swagger*** is apparently derived from the verb *swag* above, and is also quite new, first appearing in Shakespeare.  The OED provides a note from a 1598 publication that remarks that:

> > Swaggering is a new worde amongst them, and rounde headed custome giues it priuiledge with much imitation, being created as it were by a naturall *Prosopopeia* without etimologie or deriuation.

Comment: So this is good evidence that they are connected via swagger, a back and forth movement. I'd just like to point out that currently the word 'swag' by itself now means 'free stuff one gets as a gift' like in a birthday goodie bag or like a gift basket of fruit and beauty products at a fancy hotel. Also, the 'kids these days' use it for 'cool': "That is so swag, dude". None of these meanings have any connection with back and forth movement.

Comment: People will use words for _anything_. The first sense is "1. A bulgy bag. Obs." and since the OED puts it here (at the same entry) it -must- be related, even though I see no connection at all.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that they both originate from the Old Norse word *sveigja*, whose meaning is quite similar to that of *swag* and *sway*. So, yes, they might be cognates.

Comment: given that there are resources that can adequately answer this question, supposition is not needed.

Comment: It also might be a phonosemantic assonance, like [kl-](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/kl-chart.pdf). I'm travelling and away from my sources at the moment, but I think _swerve, sway, swing, swat, swoon,_ and maybe _swill_ might refer to rotatory motion. On va voir.